# Parsing through SoapUI xml response and iterate through the nodes

Tags: xpath, xml-parsing, soapui

I am currently trying to write a script to assert the response from a REST service. 
The service retrieve from the database multiple instances of a calendar event, in other words the recurring instances of the calendar event. 
The soapui response looks like below:

```
<Response>
    <items>
        <e>
            <summary>blah blah</summary>
            <start>blah blah</start>
        </e>
        <e>
            <summary>blah blah</summary>
            <start>blah blah</start>
        </e>
        <e>
            <summary>blah blah</summary>
            <start>blah blah</start>
        </e>
    </items>
</Response>
```

I want to loop though each node //Response/items/e and assert the value returned by the server. 
I try using getValueNodes and returning the array into a variable, but I can't seem to get it to work. 
Help is much appreciated.

Assane

Comment: What environment/language are you working with?

Comment: sorry for the late response, i just got back to this, it's soapui non pro version 4.0.1 on a mac and I am writing groovy script assertions to verify the response from the REST calls my web service is making

Answer (score 2):

Use the `XmlSlurper` to read the XML data and turn it into an object - see this page for reference:

http://groovy.codehaus.org/Reading+XML+using+Groovy%27s+XmlSlurper

You will need to add a `Script` test step to use it.